# Put text and image over lines

Tags: date, signatures

I found a way to put the date and signature lines as shown in the picture and with the following LaTeX code, but I am struggling with figuring out how to put the date and an image a signature over the lines without moving everything.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Images/} }
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\newcommand*\wildcard[2][5cm]{\vspace*{2cm}\parbox{#1}{\hrulefill\par#2}}    

\begin{document}

\input{Chapters/Affidavit}
\vspace{4cm}
\begingroup
  \centering
  \wildcard{Date}
  \hspace{1cm}
  \wildcard{Signature}
  \par
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using two tabulars seems simpler:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Affidavit}

Herewith bla bla.

\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{} p{6cm} @{}}
15 June 2018\\
\hline
\scriptsize Date
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{} p{6cm} @{}}
\includegraphics[width=6cm,height=1cm]{example-image} \\
\hline
\scriptsize Signature
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order to position the text and the image above the lines, you could use a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand*\wildcard[2][5cm]{\parbox{#1}{\hrulefill\par#2}}    

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{} @{}p{0.5\textwidth}@{}}
15.06.2018 & \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=1cm]{example-image}\\
\wildcard{Date} & \wildcard{Signature}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I tried it but it is putting both the text and the image about 2-3 cm over the lines, do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @PatyQuirós: In my example, I have changed the definition of `\wildcard`.  Yours contains a `\vspace*{2cm}` that is responsible for the white space and that I removed.